# Preventing Firefox from hiding toolbar buttons in popups

Tags: firefox, toolbar

When I launch my internet banking site in Firefox 39 (current at the time of this question), the resulting popup doesn't show half my toolbar buttons, including 1Password which I use to log in. Needless to say, this is most inconvenient!

Is there a way (in `about:config` or elsewhere) to prevent popup windows from disabling/hiding toolbar buttons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mozilla keep changing defaults defaults and adding new options to mess this up. It's a really wack-a-mole game.

As of firefox-59, you have to change the defaults for:

- **browser.link.open_newwindow.restriction** (from 2 to 0, so that the next setting also applies to javascript window.open. new setting)
- **browser.link.open_newwindow** (check the default of 3 is set, this open new popups on new tabs, default since a long time)
- **browser.link.open_newwindow.override.external** (change from -1 to 2, this is one is not documented!)

sources:

- http://kb.mozillazine.org/Browser.link.open_newwindow.restriction
- http://kb.mozillazine.org/Browser.link.open_newwindow
- http://www.blog.joshuaadams.com/index.cfm/2012/4/11/Setting-Firefox-to-Open-External-Links-in-a-New-Window